# React - How to refesh component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I just finished to push data on server, however the component used to fetch data is not working as expected, here's the model:

```
import DataExport 

class DataPackage extends Component {
    DoMagic() {
        // return data array (ex: items)
    }

    render() {
       return (
       <DataExport items={this.state.items}/>
    );}
}
```

About later, whatever I did with items in `DoMagic()` also not related to `DataExport`, how can I refresh items, `DataExport` to fetch data correctly?

*Thanks for your interest!*

Comment: Could you please provide mode of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use life cycle methods.

Fetch your data in **ComponentDidMount()**

ComponentDidMount() is called as soon as the component is mounted and ready. So this is good place to initiate API calls, so load your data here and use this.setState() to set your component state here.

Comment: I wonder why DataExport not refresh items although I did this.setState({items}) in DataPackage, I know data stay in drive but what DataExport show not correct (invalid index) it is miracle if I can make something same as DataExport.refresh()

Comment: @user3536460 could you please provide mode of your code?

Comment: something related to array map, after initialized data array, it remain index for each item, after that, updated firebase will throw to my app generate conflict (that's all I can imagine) anyway I fixed issue by switch component data off while insert new data, seem it's not ... nice, intuitive ... at least it can run, thanks you interest!